# Changing node's translation affects to sibling node

Tags: transformation, godot

I have a node which looks like this tree:

FPSController (Root node, and it's KinematicBody)

- CollisionShape
- Camera
- GroundCheckRayCast

When I moved CollisionShape's location down, camera also going down together. There's no code that change Camera's translation, but why this kind of thing happens?

Another weird thing is that y position of Camera won't changed even it's clearly moved down.

Is this some kind of bug or something? Why Camera's y position was changed, also not updated it's own y position value?

Using Godot 3.1.1 and reproduced repo: https://github.com/rico345100/godot-glitch-reproduction

Comment: Moving a sibling should not affect another sibling. Can you provide a minimal example, or detailed repro steps? What version of Godot are you using?

Comment: @rcorre Using Godot 3.1.1 and here's the reproduced repo: https://github.com/rico345100/godot-glitch-reproduction

Comment: I gave it a try and it doesn't repro for me. When I move the collision shape down in the editor, the camera does not move. When I start the scene and press the crouch button, the camera does not move. I'm also on godot 3.1.1

Comment: @rcorre I don't know why but it's still happening to me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. This caused because when height of CollisionShape was changed, KinematicBody responded and overall height was reduced and that's why my camera was moved.